# Custom Scoring Function in Spark Machine Learning

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, grid-search

In sklearn there is the make_scorer function that allows you to define custom scoring functions to be inserted into GridsearchCV. How can I do the same thing in Spark ML as well? For example, in the MultiClassClassificationEvaluator in spark, there is no provision to pass in a custom scoring function.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/evaluation/MulticlassClassificationEvaluator.html

Ideally, I would like the below interface. Has anyone done this before?

```
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName=CustomScoringFunction)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno added clarification